# Best way to manage multiple threads and multiple jobs

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am a bit confused on how best to do the following.  I am not after the code, but rather what I should do and when.

I want to do the following

```
get a list of shops (model query)
    create a pool for each shop (pool1, pool2, pool3)
    for each shop get all the products
        process each product by adding it to the pool, so pool1-product1,pool1-product2
```

The above shows that I have lots of shop and each shop has lots of products that need to be processed.  I want the shops to be processed at the same time

I am confused on what is the best way to approach this

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Grant

Comment: What does "process[ing] each product" entail? Is it purely cpu-bound work or dependent on some sort of input/output?

Comment: Processing each product means that I read some values from a database, a few api calls to get some data, some Pythion functions I then push to an api.  The about of data to process and deal with each time is quite small.  Does that help?

Comment: Were you planning to use multiprocessing or multithreading? Multithreading would be ideal here imo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to parallelize I/O-bound tasks (tasks consisting mostly of network calls and other I/Os). You can either use a cooperative multitasking library such as [AsyncIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) of use a thread pool for that. Here is what it could look like using a [thread pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html):

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def process_product(product):
  ...

def process_shop(shop):
  for product in shop.products:
    process_product(product)

def main():
  shops = [...]

  with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(process_shop, shops)
```

Usually, you do not want to create a new thread for each shop as it could be expensive and inefficient, hence the use of a pool.

With AsyncIO, you can use the [`gather()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) function to launch concurrent tasks. It would ressembles:

```py
import asyncio

async def process_product(product):
  ...

async def process_shop(shop):
  for product in shop.products:
    await process_product(product)

async def main():
  shops = [...]

  await asyncio.gather(*[process_shop(shop) for shop in shops])
  

if __name__ == "__main__":
  asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Just so am am clear.  The best approach is to create a pool with all the products, from more that one shop, in one big pool, and let Python manage that pool?

Comment: I don’t pretend it’s the best approach but it is definitely an easy, efficient and safe way to manage concurrent tasks.

Comment: In my example, shops are processed concurrently but not the products within a shop. You could chose to also make concurrent the products processing if it’s relevant to your application.

Comment: Thanks for helping on this, and making it clear.